Как вывести свойство объекта из js в html
Пример:

my.salary = 2 или my['salary'] = 2 перенести в html (Желаемое поведение)
document.write(my.salary) - Не работает (Конкретная проблема)
Смотрел в интернете, пока вопрос остается не решенным.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Приведите полный пример кода, который не работает

Вывод значений в HTML, в общем виде выглядит так:
Получаем HTML элемент, с которым собираемся взаимодействовать(getElement*, querySelector*)
Присваиваем данному элементу желаемое значение


// Создали объект
const my = {
  salary: 0
}
// Изменили значение ключа(чисто для демонстрации)
my.salary = 100;
// Выбираем элемент из DOM(по атрибуту id)
const show = document.getElementById('show');
// Присваиваем элементу значение
show.innerText = my.salary;
<div id="show"></div>




Действительно, это решает вопрос, просто я не создал объекта изначально, но уже начал с ним работать, данный пример решил этот вопрос, конкретно добавление - "const my = {
salary: 0
}"
